# How does the topology in Blender relate to the mathematical topology?

Tags: topology, mathematics

In many videos of Blender that I have seen, it goes over the topic of "topology" what I seem to think it is about is about setting a grid line on the surface / seeing the inverse of the grid line of chart. Could someone explain what this thing is precisely and how it relates to what mathematicians consider topology?

Comment: Topology in 3D modelling usually refers to how a mesh surface is "constructed" - the placement of vertices as well as the edges and faces joining them is the "base" of the topology, but the term can be used to describe a myriad of things from here - topology could refer to how the mesh actually looks, or could refer to the type of faces used to construct it (ie tri-based for triangles or quad-based for quads). Topology can also refer to the overall "flow" of face and edge loop direction around a mesh.

Comment: The way modellers use the term and the way mathematicians use the term are more different than a modeller's and an archeologist's use of "artifact."  There is nearly no relationship.  There is some mathematical basis to modeller's "good topology"-- smoothness is a mathematical quality that we seek to maximize with our topo, and our surfaces are quantifiable, made out of numbers-- but it doesn't have anything to do with the specific mathematical discipline "topology".  Still, all math connects...

Answer (score 2):

Blender "topology" refers to how the mesh is decomposed into vertices, edges and faces, without regard to their positions. For example, the following two meshes have roughly the same shape, but the first has a more regular topology, which will make further editing easier.

[image: Mesh with regular topology]
[image: Mesh with irregular topology]

The relation with mathematical "topology" is: The connectivity between the vertices, edges and faces is exactly the information describing a 2-dimensional [CW-complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex). In particular, various mathematical topological properties can be determine from this information, such as whether the surface is a manifold with or without boundary and its genus.